# how many time a specific character repeat in a string - NetLogo

Tags: string, netlogo

I want to find every specific character for example a from my List , e.g : find "a" :

```
print position "a" "skdjhaksajab"

;=> answer : 5
```

while we have 3 position for "a" in the List : 5 and 8 and 10 , but it show only one position for 5 . 
how can I do it ?
Thanks

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 2):

After defining:

```
to-report positions [char s]
  report filter [char = item ? s]
                n-values (length s) [?]
end
```

Then we get:

```
observer> show positions "a" "skdjhaksajab"
observer: [5 8 10]
```